# clicking checkboxes make table captions move down page

Tags: html, css

I'm using custom styled checkboxes in a design.  The checkboxes work perfectly as they are designed to do on my windows laptop (tested in chrome and IE); however, on my ipad and my iphone, **the checkboxes are making the table caption's move down the page.  The more you click the checkboxes, the more the captions go down the page.**

*I've spent quite a bit of time modifying the code and cannot come up with why its happening.*

*This may be happening on a mac computer as well running safari.  I'm not sure because I am unable to test*

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.margin5 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.clear {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.table-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.table-condensed>thead>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #000 !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-bordered caption {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

caption.firstheading {
  background: #062D6A;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

caption.secondheading {
  background: #1d8cb8;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header2 {
  font-size: .85em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}

table {
  background-color: transparent;
}

caption {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  color: #777;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

.table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table>thead>tr>th,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table>thead>tr>th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>th,
.table>colgroup+thead>tr:first-child>th,
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th,
.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>td,
.table>colgroup+thead>tr:first-child>td,
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>td {
  border-top: 0;
}

.table-condensed>thead>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table-bordered>thead>tr>th,
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th,
.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-bordered>thead>tr>td,
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,
.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table-bordered>thead>tr>th,
.table-bordered>thead>tr>td {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.table-responsive {
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

form.formatted {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

form.formatted label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

form.formatted #checkbox {}

form.formatted #checkbox_label {}

form.formatted input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

form.formatted .checkbox {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

form.formatted input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.00000001;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

form.formatted .helper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #1d8cb8;
}

form.formatted .helper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: transform 0.28s ease;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
}

form.formatted .helper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 7px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1d8cb8;
  border-left: 2px solid #1d8cb8;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
}

form.formatted input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.helper::before {
  color: #1d8cb8;
}

form.formatted input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.helper::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
}

form.formatted .checkbox label {
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

form.formatted input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label::before {
  outline: rgb(59, 153, 252) auto 5px;
}
```

```html
<form class="formatted">

  <table class="table-full table-condensed table-bordered">
    <caption class="firstheading">CAPTION</caption>
    <caption class="secondheading"><i>CAPTION LINE 2</i></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header2">
        <th>
          <div class="margin5">COL 1</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="margin5">COL 2</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="margin5">COL 3</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="margin5">COL 4</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="margin5">COL 5</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="margin5">COL 6</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>TABLE CONTENT</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>BLAH BLAH</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>TABLE CONTENT</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>BLAH BLAH</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>TABLE CONTENT</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>BLAH BLAH</b></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>BLAH BLAH</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>TABLE CONTENT</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>BLAH BLAH</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>TABLE CONTENT</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>BLAH BLAH</b></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="margin5"><b>TABLE CONTENT</b></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
          <div class="margin5">
            <div class="clear"><br /></div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td class="td-left" colspan="6">
          <div class="margin5">

            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1"><i class="helper"></i> 1 </label></div><br /><br />
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2"><i class="helper"></i> 2 </label></div><br /><br />
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3"><i class="helper"></i> 3 </label></div><br /><br />
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4"><i class="helper"></i> 4 </label></div><br /><br />

          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</form>
```

Comment: I verified that this bug is also occurring on desktop Safari, but apparently only when the browser window is somewhat narrow.

Comment: @mfluehr - Thank you for that!  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The window size doesn't seem to matter after all, although resizing the window fixes the issue (until you click a checkbox again). I can't seem to identify a fix, though.

Comment: I tried a different coding to see if it helped but it did the same thing.   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp